# Missing "Create alert" icon in Google scholar search results page?

Tags: google-search, google-scholar

The "Create Alert" button is missing from my Google Scholar search results page. How can I restore it or create an alert without it?

Let's say I run this advanced search in Google Scholar, 
[image]
which returns a results page,
[image]
[Google says](http://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/help.html) there should be a "Create Alert" envelope icon on the result page, but it is missing. How can I restore it? Or is there another way to create a Google Scholar alert which gets emailed every time a certain journal is published with a chosen search term in the title?

Answer (score 1):

A kind librarian at the Boston Library Consortium answered this for me,

If you go to Google Scholar's [page](https://scholar.google.com/), it will have an "Alerts" icon at the top
and after you click on that, it will have a red button for creating an alert
then you put in a query and save it.

So in the example, the query would be

allintitle: hamster Publication: "journal of agricultural and food chemistry"